# When can I delete a file after using it in Response.WriteFile()?

Tags: asp.net

Is the WriteFile call properly synchronous, and can I delete the file written immediately after the call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fully synchronous, as you can see by looking at the implementation of `HttpResponse.WriteFile` with Lutz Reflector.  You can delete the file immediately after the call to `Response.WriteFile`.

You don't have the guarantee that the response stream has been completely transmitted to the client, but calling `Response.Flush` doesn't give you that guarantee either.  So I don't see a need to call `Response.Flush` before deleting the file.

Avoid loading the file into a `MemoryStream`, it brings you no benefit, and has a cost in memory usage, especially for large files.

Comment: I just tested this and in theory I agree, but in practice I don't. The documentation indicates it is sychronous, but I just verified that in my environment (VS 2010, dev server, .Net 4) you have to call **Response.Flush**, or the file will be deleted before it can be returned.

Answer (score 9):

If you're writing a file to the client with `Response.WriteFile()`, a call to `Response.Flush()` will make sure it's been fully output to the client. Once that's done you can delete it off of the webserver.

You may want to come up with a more robust system if the file is mission-critical. Say, a client-side script to validate that the file was received OK and then alerts the webserver that the file can be deleted.

Comment: For me the following approach worked: `Response.Flush(); Response.Close(); File.Delete(path);`

Answer (score 5):

That is the solution, after use the syntax `Response.WriteFile(fileName);`, type the following code lines:

```
Response.Flush();
System.IO.File.Delete(fullPathFileName);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Avoid using Response.End() whenever possible. It throws uncatchable exception and aborts thread. It's better to use `Response.SuppressContent = true; HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); return;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves it is synchronous, as are the rest of the RESPONSE commands.

Answer (score 0):

**TransmitFile**

You can also call TransmitFile to let IIS take care of it.  It actually gets sent by IIS outside of your worker processs.

**Memory Stream**

If you are REALLY paranoid, don't send the file.  Load it into a memory stream (if the size is reasonable) and transmit that.  Then you can delete the file whenever you like.  The file on disk will never be touched by IIS.