# C# download and delete file

Tags: c#, file, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can I delete a file after using it in Response.WriteFile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200901/when-can-i-delete-a-file-after-using-it-in-response-writefile)

I'm using the following code to download temp file then delete it but, the last statement is not executed, how can I do that

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
Response.Clear();
Response.WriteFile(sFilePath);
//Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(sFilePath));            
Response.End();
File.Delete(sFilePath);
```

Comment: What do you mean is not executed. Did you tried to put a breakpoint?

Comment: Isn't it becouse you ending the response with `Response.End();` before executing the last line?

Comment: `Response.End()` aborts the current thread. Why do you need it? Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200901/when-can-i-delete-a-file-after-using-it-in-response-writefile

Comment: Just to be clear this is a c# application and not the backend of a MVC / asp.net type program? (because there are better ways to handle this in a web scenario)